# how to explode a column and join it to dataframe as frequency categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to join a main dataframe with a nested dict extracted in another dataframe

main dataframe
[image]

extracted dict

[image]

expected outcome
[image]

This is what i have tried

```
x = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(genres['name'])], axis=1)
```

x

[image]

Comment: Do you what to join the dataframes on id? For future notice, do not post images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
hot = pd.get_dummies(df.pop('genre').explode().str['name']).groupby(level=0).max()
df = pd.concat([df, hot], axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
    id original_title  Action  Comedy  Drama
0  123          Hello       1       0      1
1  456          World       0       1      0
```

Input data:

```
data = {'genre': [[{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}], 
                  [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]],
        'id': [123, 456], 'original_title': ['Hello', 'World']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
                                               genre   id original_title
0  [{'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 28, 'name...  123          Hello
1                     [{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]  456          World
```

Comment: this gave me the expected result, although i needed to copy the main dataframe because pop removes the column genres that i need to explode into seperate genres table

Comment: I used `pop` because in your original question you used it. If you don't need it, just replace `df.pop('genre')` by `df['genre']`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, you have only one dataframe, df, and you have just exploded the one column including the genre and try to merge it back to the original dataframe. In that case, you do not need to do it this way. Just use this function. It'll fatten the entire dataframe.

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(exploded.columns)  # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            # print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

Do, then

```
flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

and it should given you what you expected.

If it is so that you have 2 dataframes, df1 (which you want to flatten) and df2 to merge to, do the same thing with df1 and then:

```
df_final = df1.merge(df2, on = ['id'])
```